# JPA - OneToMany with OR condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have 2 SQL tables, "node" and "edge".

The "node" table has a composite primary key, which consists of two columns: "id" and "type".

The "edge" table contains the following columns:

- node_1_id: the id of the first node of the edge
- node_1_type: the type of the first node of the edge
- node_2_id: the id of the second node of the edge
- node_2_type: the type of the second node of the edge

There are also two foreign key constraints that link ("node_1_id", "node_1_type") and ("node_2_id", "node_2_type") to the "id" and "type" of the "node" table.

I've created the following jpa entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "edge")
public class Edge {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "node_1_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "node_1_type", referencedColumnName = "type")
    })
    private Node node1;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "node_2_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "node_2_type", referencedColumnName = "type")
    })
    private Node node2;
}
```

In "Node" entity I would like to create a "OneToMany" relation called "edges" that fetches all the edges linked to a node (it doesn't matter if it is the first or the second node).

This is the correspondent SQL query:

```
select *
from node n join edge e
on (n.id = e.node_1_id and n.type = e.node_1_type) or (n.id = e.node_2_id and n.type = e.node_2_type)
where n.id = 1 and n.type = 'type';
```

How can I create such relation?

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to be a single `@OneToMany` relationship? Otherwise you could add the counterparts to the two `@ManyToOne` relationships and create a getter that simply returns a single, merged list:

```
public class Node {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="node1")
    private List<Edge> firstNodeEdges;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="node2")
    private List<Edge> secondNodeEdges;

    public List<Edge> getEdges() {
        return Stream.concat(firstNodeEdges.stream(), secondNodeEdges.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, in my particular case it should be a `@OneToMany` relationship.